# going to method, pulling info from file, and then returning it after it gets split. I am getting errors

Tags: java, arrays, methods, io

```
String[] quarters = new String[100] ;   
quarters[] = information(fileCheck) ;

public static string information(String a)
    {   
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner (new File(a)) ; // opens connection with file

        while (inFile.hasNext())                        // loops while more lines in file
        {
            String line = inFile.nextLine() ;           // brings in next line to be broken up
            String[] tokens = line.split(", ") ;        //stores lines into array tokens
        }       
            inFile.close() ;                            // close connection to file
            return tokens[] ;
    } // end information
```

Comment: Please tell us the details: What are you trying to do ? What errors are you getting? We'll be able to do a much better job at helping you if you first help us understand your problem.

Comment: Ill post the errors in a sec, basically this is part of my full code which i can also post at request. Basically I cannot figure out why there are errors with the quarters array. I need to use it later as well.

Comment: Please post the errors and the information about your problem as an edit to your original post, not as a comment.

Comment: not a statement
 quarters[] = information(fileCheck) ;

Comment: ';' expected
 quarters[] = information(fileCheck) ;

Comment: '.class' expected
   return tokens[] ;

Comment: Again, edit your original question as this is all *essential* information that deserves to be in the question, not in a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not Java:

```
return tokens[] ;
```

Perhaps you mean to return the token array:

```
return tokens;
```

If so, declare the method to return `String[]` not `String`.

Also, you're not showing us where these lines are located:

```
String[] quarters = new String[100] ;   
quarters[] = information(fileCheck) ;
```

For all we know they are sitting out naked in the class and not in any method or constructor. If so, that is not Kosher Java since the second line is not a declaration and needs to be in a method or constructor.

Comment: thanks for the first part and as for the second they are in the main method (public static void main(String[] args)) if that helps.

Comment: @ConnorElliott: you're welcome. If you've solved your question than accept my answer. If not, then update your original question adding any new code, where you try to correct the error and describe *in detail* the current problem.